# regex match accentuated characted in VBA

Tags: regex, vba

I have a French word document in which I would like to find some numbers located near a specific word:

```
Sub RegexTest1()
Dim Str As String
Dim regMatch As String

Dim objRegex As RegExp
Dim num
Str = " Évaluation 423"
regMatch = "\b" & "[EÉ]valuation\s{1,3}(\d+)"
Set objRegex = New RegExp

  With objRegex
        .Pattern = regMatch
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Set matches = .Execute(Str)
        For Each fnd In matches
            num = fnd.SubMatches(0)
            MsgBox num
        Next fnd
  End With

End Sub
```

The code above works (423 is output to the box) if Str="Evaluation 423",  but if Str="Évaluation 423"  with the accentuated É,  it fails.  How can I add the accentuated character to the character set?

Comment: It seems the extended chars are converted to `?`, try `regMatch = "(?:\bE|\B\?)valuation\s{1,3}(\d+)"`, and if it works, this is the issue. Another issue is that `\b` in ECMAScript is not Unicode-aware, and `\bÉ` will fail anyway since `É` is not a word char acc. to `\b`. The workaround will depend on what letters you want to support, all or just a subset.

Comment: yes !just tested, the issue is \b not being unicode aware,  as a quick hacky fix sufficient for me I just replaced \b with [ ] (a space) which  will work for my documents.

Comment: No, do not just use space. Use `regMatch = "(?:\s|^)[EÉ]valuation\s{1,3}(\d+)"` to also match at the string start.